# jquery dataTable change pages

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

everyone! I need to change pagination in dataTable. I got this [image: I got this]

And I need to change to that

[image]

I tried to change css like this

```
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled{
    margin-left:100px;
}
```

but I failed. Have you got any ideas?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please post what you've tried, StackOverflow is not a code-generator service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a table with `pagingType` as `full_numbers`

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  pagingType: "full_numbers"
});
```

you can hide the first and prev buttons this way

```js
$('#example').on('draw.dt', function() {
  $('.paginate_button.previous,.paginate_button.first').hide();
});
```

and it looks like your image above - demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/n5dyy8px/**